# Reflection not finding protected field of nested type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class, which has a **protected nested class**, and a **protected readonly field** of the nested class' type.
My framework calls

```
o.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

on an instance of the type, I can see the field from debugger, but the call doesn't return it. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You also need to include `BindingFlags.Instance`

> Instance - Specifies that instance
>   members are to be included in the
>   search.

from

[BindingFlags Enumeration (System.Reflection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You should also specify `BindingFlags.Instance` if it's a non-static field.

If it's a static field, add `BindingFlags.Static` and `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`.